# Oracle SOA Suite 12c invoke external service with additional SOAP headers

Tags: soap, soa, bpel, soa-suite

I have a business scenario where I have to invoke a client SOAP service that uses additional SOAP header parameters using Oracle SOA Suite 12c. When I test the web service independently via SOAP UI it shows below schema as input-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://xmlns.client.org/Schema/Common/1.0/Common.xsd" xmlns:user="http://xmlns.uppcl.org/Schema/UserAccess/2.0/UserAccess.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header>
   <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.demo-open.org/wss/2004/01/demo-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.demo-open.org/wss/2004/01/demo-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>DemoUser</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Demo@123</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
      <com:TransactionReference>
         <com:SourceSystemId>TXNSYSID</com:SourceSystemId>
         <com:TxID>0403216376127836</com:TxID>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <com:BusinessID>DTUIQS</com:BusinessID>
      </com:TransactionReference>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <user:CheckUserRequest>
  <user:UserId>USER_ID</user:UserId>
  </user:CheckUserRequest>
```

As we can see additional header elements wsse:Security > UsernameToken  > Username/Password , TransactionReference > SourceSystemId / TxID / BusinessID as XML node.

Further, I configured the SOAP adapter in my SOA composite but it has only one input argument UserId. Now I am not able to figure out how can I pass additional headers (username/password, SourceSystemId / TxID / BusinessID  ) in SOA Header for target web service invocation in my SOA composite.

Comment: have you seen these?  
https://biemond.blogspot.com/2012/04/retrieve-or-set-http-header-from-oracle.html   

https://rohanlopes.blogspot.com/2016/03/passingreceiving-http-header-in-soa-bpel.html

Comment: does your target webservice require wsse security? Otherwise you could switch it off in SOAPUI. You could play around with the settings and look at the raw request and see how it plays with the header.

Comment: @Jesper Vernooij, yes the target web service uses wsse security and additional security payload in TransactionReference .

Comment: You can create your header variables on scope level or globally and add them in the "Edit Invoke" step of your BPEL. Just double click the invoke, click headers, click browse variables and add the requested variable. It will be added to your header in the payload.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

add this snippet to omitt default wsa tags

`<binding.ws> <property name="oracle.soa.ws.outbound.omitWSA" type="xs:boolean" many="false" override="may">true</property> </binding.ws>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).